# How to interpret the output of H2O .predict method for random forest classification?

Tags: python, random-forest, h2o

When I use the `predict` method on my trained model I get an output that is 1 row and 206 columns. it seems to have 206 values ranging in values from 0-1. This sort of makes sense as the model's output is categorical variable with values 0 and 1 as possible values. But I don't get the 206 values, as I understand it the output should be a value of 0 or 1. What do the 206 values mean?

I've spent the past hour or so browsing h2o documentation but can't seem to find an explanation of how to explain the 206 values outputted by predict when I was expecting one value that is either a 0 or 1.

thanks.

Comment: Please provide some context. You use `predict` on what? A single sample? A test set? And if it is the second, how many samples does it include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT: The first column is the answer that your model is choosing. The remaining 205 columns are the prediction confidences for each of the 205 categories. (It implies whatever you are trying to predict is a factor (aka enum) column with 205 levels.) Those 205 columns should be summing to 1.0.

The column names should be a good clue: the first column is "predict", but the others are the labels of each of your 205 categories.

---

(Old answer, based on assuming it was 206 rows, 1 column!)

If predict is giving you a single column of output you have done a *regression*, not a classification.

> This sort of makes sense as the model's output is categorical variable with values 0 and 1 as possible values.

H2O has seen those 0s and 1s and assumed they are numbers, not categories. To do a classification you simply need to change that column to be an enum (H2O's internal term for it), aka factor (the R/Python H2O API term for it). (Do this step immediately after loading your data into H2O, and before splitting it or making any models.)

E.g. if `data` is your H2O Frame, and `answer` is the name of your column with the 0 and 1 catgeories in it, you would do:

```
data["answer"] = data["answer"].asfactor()
```

If any of your other columns look numeric but should actually be treated as factors, you can do multiple columns at once like this:

```
factorsList = ["cat1", "cat2", "answer"]
data[factorsList] = data[factorsList].asfactor()
```

You can also set the column types at the time you [import the data with the col_types argument](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html#h2o.import_file).

Comment: thank you for the very detailed response! I have actually done a classification and had set the output column to be an enum. This makes sense given the context you provided as my output does in fact have multiple columns. I guess my problem is I don't know how to interpret the columns. I am only running the predict method on ONE row so i'm not sure how to interpret the 206 columns in the output of predict.

Comment: @majorcoder Aha! Sorry, I'd missed "1 row" in your question. I've updated my answer.